# Beginnings of a Scraper in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm teaching myself Python, by doing instead of just reading.
When I run this code terminal isn't displaying an error, but nothing is happening, although it seems to me that this should be retrieving the address from this listing.

Is there something wrong with how I'm calling this data?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing/bulldog-gym/")
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
print soup.prettify()

listing_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"tab-contents"})
for item in listing_data:
    print item.contents[0].find_all("span",{"class":"wlt_shortcode_map_location"})[0].text
```

Comment: Should I guess what do you want to do? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: listing_data is an empty list, which is why nothing gets printed.  Try soup.find_all("div") and explore from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual problem is quite simple but there's other problems you'll uncover. The major issue, is the first class you're looking for is `tab-content` (no `s`).

You'll then discover that there's two `tab-content` classes on the page. The second iteration causes an exception as the structure is different.

As there's only one use of `wlt_shortcode_map_location` in the page, you can simply recursively look for it from the top level.

Later you may find issues with encoding - `r.content` is the raw bytes from the request where as `r.text` is the decoded string using the server's content-type as a guide.

With all this in mind, the following code seems to do what you want:

```
url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing/bulldog-gym/")
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

print soup.find("span",{"class":"wlt_shortcode_map_location"}).text
```

Good luck with your coding!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the easy to understand explanation too.. My first question and answer on Stack ;)